# Add data from 2 JSON files into a single JSON File Using Python in AWS S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 json files patienta.json, patient_b.json i want to extract data from these 2 json and load it into a single json patient.json in aws s3. below is the code i am using but it is over writing the content of json. please help

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import boto3
import json
import decimal

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
print(bucket)
print(json_file_name)
json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key = json_file_name)
jsonFileReader = json_object['Body'].read()
jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFileReader)
object = s3.Object('anand-fhir-json', 'Patient_Resource/patient.json')
for patient in jsonDict:
    try:
        id = str(jsonDict['id'])
    except:
        id = 'null'
    try:
        resourceType = str(jsonDict['resourceType'])
    except:
        resourceType = 'null'
    try:
        identifier = str(jsonDict['identifier'][0]['value'])
    except:
        identifier = 'null'
    try:
        active = str(jsonDict['active'])
    except:
        active = 'null'
    try:
        firstname = str(jsonDict['name'][0]['family'])
    except:
        firstname = 'null'
    try:
        lastname = str(jsonDict['name'][0]['given'][0])
    except:
        lastname = 'null'
    try:
        gender = str(jsonDict['gender'])
    except:
        gender = 'null'
    try:
        managingOrganization_ref = str(jsonDict['managingOrganization']['reference'])
    except:
        managingOrganization_ref = 'null'
    try:
        managingOrganization_display = str(jsonDict['managingOrganization']['display'])
    except:
        managingOrganization_display = 'null'


#for patient in object:
object.put(Body=json.dumps({
'id': id,
'resourceType': resourceType,
'identifier': identifier,
'active': active,
'firstname': firstname,
'lastname': lastname,
'gender': gender,
'managingOrganization_ref': managingOrganization_ref,
'managingOrganization_display': managingOrganization_display,
 }))
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug this on your own? Can you break this down into a minimal example triggering the problem?

Comment: There is no error. It simple puts data for patient a and ignores patient b json.